# Dynamic Frame writing extra columns

Tags: pyspark, amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have a glue task that is reading in data from S3, running a couple of SQL queries on the data, and outputting the data to Redshift.  I am having an odd problem where   when writing the `dynamic_frame` to Redshift(using `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options`) new columns are being created.  These are some of my existing columns with the type appended to the end.  For example if my frame schema is as follows:

```
id: string
value: short
value2: long
ts: timestamp
```

In Redshift I am seeing:

```
id varchar(256)
value: smallint    <---- The data here is always null
value2: bigint     <---- The data here is always null
ts: timestamp      
value_short: smallint
value2_long: bigint
```

The  `value_short` and `value2_long` columns are being created at time of exection(currently testing with creds that have `alter table` permissions)

When looking at the `COPY` command that was run I am seeing the columns `value_short` and `value2_long` in the command.  I am not seeing the columns present in the dynamic frame before that is being written with `glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options`

Comment: What do you get when doing a printSchema on the dynamic frame? I suspect you get some choice. And then need to run resolveChoice.

Comment: When doing `printSchema` the line before my write_dynamic_frame it prints out: `|-- value: short` and `|-- value2: long`, I don't see anything related to choices(I haven't had to deal with them before however).  Looking at the log output the only place I see `value_short` is in CREATE TABLE statement: `RedshiftWriter: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table ( id VARCHAR(MAX), value_short INTEGER, value2_long INTEGER, ts TIMESTAMP )`  So for some reason it is seeing it as a integer.  I am almost positive my values are in-bounds, but I am guessing I can declare the types as ints to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Casting the types explicitly as aloissiola suggested solved this problem for me. Specifically, I used the **dynamicFrame.resolveChoice** function:

```
changetypes = select1.resolveChoice(
        specs=[
            ("value", "cast:int"),
            ("value2", "cast:int")
        ]
    )
```

It looks like you can cast to short and long types as well. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-types.html I went through and specified types for all my columns.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to cast the short value to integer. Long -> bigint seems working for me.